# C++ OutputDebugStringW with newline

Tags: c++, windows, outputdebugstring

I want to attach a new line to the OutputDebugStringW.

```
OutputDebugStringW(Item.pItem);
```

pItem is a LPCWSTR, not a wstring, so I could not directly add new line by saying + "/n".

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just output the newline in a separate call to `OutputDebugStringW`:

```
OutputDebugStringW(Item.pItem);
OutputDebugStringW(L"\n");
```

If for some reason you only want to make a single call to `OutputDebugStringW`, build a string first:

```
std::wstringstream ss;
ss << Item.pItem << L"\n";
OutputDebugStringW(ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Ah, I tried that, but I used "/" instead of "\". Thank you very much.

Comment: could you perhaps also tell me how to OutputDebugWString an int? I would like to say something like OutputDebugStringW(L"Counter: " + iCounter);

Comment: @tmighty: Use a wstringstream as in my second example: `ss << L"Counter: " << iCounter;`.

Comment: @tmighty, Or `std::to_wstring(iCounter).c_str()`.